# What are the Fourier Transform of this function?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, analytic-number-theory, harmonic-analysis

We know that the Fourier transform for Riemann $\Xi$

${\displaystyle \Xi (t)=\xi ({\frac  12}+it) }$

where:

$\xi (s)={\tfrac  {1}{2}}s(s-1)\pi ^{{-s/2}}\Gamma \left({\tfrac  {1}{2}}s\right)\zeta (s)$

The Fourier transform of $\Xi(t)$ is:

$\Xi (t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\Phi(u)e^{iut}\,du$

Where:

$\Phi(u) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (4\pi^2n^4e^{9u/2}  - 6n^2\pi e^{5u/2} ) exp(-n^2\pi e^{2u})$

But, what are the Fourier transform for Dirichlet L function ?

$ {\Lambda(s,\chi) = \left(\frac{\pi}{k}\right)^{-(s+a)/2}\Gamma\left(\frac{s+a}{2}\right) L(s,\chi) }$

where symbol $a$:

$ {a=\begin{cases}0;    \mbox{if }\chi(-1)=1, \\ 1;\mbox{if }\chi(-1)=-1,\end{cases}}$

Can anyone help with this question ?  or can you provide a reference ?

(For example, for Dirichlet $\eta$ function, what is its Fourier Transform after consider $\Gamma(s/2)$ and $\pi ^{{-s/2}}$ adjustment ? )

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: $\Lambda(\sigma+i \omega,\chi)$ is the Fourier transform of something like $f_\chi(u) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi(n) n^a \exp(-n^2\pi e^{2u}/k) e^{- u (\sigma-a)}$.

Comment: Thank you ! @reuns, Are there similar results on critical line ?

Comment: For $\chi$ non-principal it converges everywhere.  The core of those things is that for $\chi$ a primtive Dirichlet character $\bmod k$ then by the Poisson summation formula $h_\chi(x) = \beta^{-1} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \chi(n) n^{a} e^{-n^2 x/k} = x^{-a/2} h_{\overline{\chi}}(1/x)$ where $a=(1-\chi(-1))/2$ and $\beta = \frac{\sum_{n=1}^k \chi(n) e^{2i \pi n/k}}{k^{1/2}}, |\beta| = 1$

Comment: @reuns, thank you again !  I do not understand why we need "$\chi$ non-principal" condition in your statement.  By looking the expression for $f_\chi(u)$, it seems that $f_\chi(u)$  should converge everywhere even for principal character, right ? Plus, $\Lambda(s,\chi)$ should also be well defined everywhere, right ?